# How do I configure Webstorm 10 to run npm install --force before debugging?

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm

I have a shared submodule that requires me to run "npm install --force" before I can run webstorm and debug the application.  I would really like to edit my debug configuration to have a before launch action that will run the npm command for me.  Can this be done?

Comment: my application is a nodejs web service, in case it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At counfiguration window ( where you set up debug configuration ) you can find 'Before launch' section

See more at https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html ( search on page by 'Before launch')

> **Before launch** Specify which tasks must be performed before applying the run/debug configuration. The specified tasks are
>   performed in the order they appear in the list.

[image]

Comment: I see that.. I tried to add a "Before Launch, Run External Tools (configured to run Terminal.app) passing parameters of "npm install --force" but that doesn't work... any ideas on the rest of the configuration?  (I am on OSX)

Comment: why do you think that it doesn't work? You can check all 'Show console' options. And can you share screen of your 'Create tool' dialog?

Comment: it seems to fail on the force?

Comment: open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app npm install --force
open: unrecognized option `--force'
Usage: open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b <bundle identifier>] [-a <application>] [filenames] [--args arguments]
......

Comment: sadly my reputation is so new, I can't upload images yet

Comment: Program: /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app       Parameters: "npm install --force"    Working Directory:   /Applications/Utilities

Comment: You don't have to run your Terminal app. The external tool in your case should be npm itself. Specify the path to npm, e.g. /usr/local/bin/npm as a program. Parameter should be install -f. Working directory is the folder that WebStorm would sync with the file system after the command is executed, so it should be $ProjectFileDir$.